# Looking for a detailed example of proof by reduction

Tags: signature, provable-security

I'm looking for a very detailed example of proof by reduction. Say we have two or three protocols (that have been proven secure) and we construct a new protocol. We want to provide a proof of security for this new protocol.

For instance, we can consider the following simple example: we have a (secure) signature algorithm $D$ and a (secure) hash function $H$ and we construct the following signature algorithm (denoted $N$) that takes input the secret key $sk$ for $D$ and a message $M$ :

- We compute $d=H(M)$;
- We compute $s=D.Sign_{sk}(d)$ and ouput $s$.

(We can deduce the verification algorithm)

This kind of new algorithm is not useful (we add a hash function to a signature algorithm that has already a hash function embedded in it) but I think it can be used to show an example of proof by reduction.

So, we have an adversary $A$ that can break $N$ in time $t$, with $q$ queries and an advantage less than $\epsilon$. We want to show that:

- we can build an adversary $A'$ against $D$ that runs in time $t'$, with $q'$ queries and having an advantage $\epsilon'$
- we can build an adversary $A''$ against $H$ that runs in time $t''$ with $q''$ queries and having an advantage $\epsilon''$

What is a correct proof by reduction? How to use $A$ to build $A'$ and $A''$ ? and what is the relation between the times $t$, $t'$, $t''$, the relation between the advantages, etc ?

Comment: @Minkus CNB It's not surprising that this looks like a homework.

Comment: Can the reduction use the oracle for $H$ and the oracle for $D$ to respond to queries from $N$ ?

Comment: This can be no more homework. May be someone wants to give an answer?

Comment: There are many examples of proofs by reduction here and elsewhere. What's the point of this question?

Comment: Intuitively I'd use game-hopping instead of a reduction for this problem. First swap out the hash function for some injective function (if you can distinguish this, then you can break the collision resistance) then it's an injective mapping to a secure signature which should be somewhat easily be proven secure using a reduction.